# Query "object.filter" to return list for rendering CharFields

Tags: python, django

If I have a table like this:

```
ID | option | outcome
131    129      3
132    129      2
133    129      1
```

How can I write an objects.get script such that I am able to either grab the IDs or outcomes for option = 129.

```
outcomes=myTable.objects.filter(option=129)
```

does not seem to work. I'm looking for a list/array that is something like outcomes = [131,132,133] or [1,2,3] so that I can have a for loop like this:

```
 for outcomevalue in outcomes:
       self.fields['outcomevalue_%s' % outcomevalue.pk] = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

and it will produce 3 CharFields

Comment: you're using %s, but it should be %d for an int, perhaps that's your problem? Otherwise your code should work based on what you've shown.

Comment: >>> print '%s' % 1
1
>>>

Answer (score 0):

```
list(myTable.objects.filter(option=129).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: the code does not render such that there are 3 CharFields. I believe my object.filter code and yours may be outputting 3 values, but maybe there is something wrote with the for loop?